# How do I find the screen size in a fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was looking at this posting:  [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)  when I was trying to determine the size of the device's screen while in a fragment class.  One answer was close to what I needed but the only code that ended up working for me was:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getView().getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
Display screen = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

whereupon I could then use getHeight(); or another non-deprecated term.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @Manfred Moser: This question was about how to return the screen dimensions from within a fragment class of whatever device is using an application with this code(ie 320x480).  If you have any suggestions about how to improve this question I can definitely clarify the wording. Thanks.

Comment: you are not supposed to edit the question to contain the answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You questions contains the answer! Just use getActvity() as the context in the fragment.

Comment: Dont post tutorials on stackoverflow as questions. Answer other questions and if you have tutorials.. post them on your blog. Basically read the FAQ.